# Want to validate email address in JavaScript but can't figure out how to include only one @ in the character string

Tags: javascript, html, string, email

So far I have this:

```
function validateForm() {
var str=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var atpos=str.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=str.lastIndexOf(".com");
   if (atpos>0 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=str.length) 
 {
   alert("Incorrect e-mail address");
   return false;
  }
}
```

How can I include the '@' to be shown ONCE in the character string? (So an email can't be validated as @@).

I also would appreciate it if it were anything but the regex method.

Comment: `/@[^@]*@/`.. this regex should work I suppose. like: `!
/(@[^@]*@|^[^@]+$)/.test(emailString);`

Comment: @Mr_Green ...and the asker wants a non-regex method.

Comment: @Pietu1998 oops yes. thought opposite of it :)

Comment: BTW, for validating emails, devs should prefer regex. -1

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want use regex, you can split a string by an occurrence.

```
var email = "foor@bar.com";
if((email.split('@').length != 2) {
    // it's not an email address
}
else {
    // it is an email address
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice hack is to check if the first @ is also the last @.

```
if(str.indexOf('@') != -1 && str.indexOf('@') == str.lastIndexOf('@')){
    // email is valid
}
```

Comment: +1 though this a good trick I suggest the OP should go with Tommi's answer because emails can be validated using regex only.

Comment: @Mr_Green True; I would do it with regex myself, and I will happily recommend it to the OP, but as the question asked for a non-regex one, I came up with this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this buddy

```
function validateForm()
{
    var x=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
    var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
    {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to validate the email address is through regular expressions:

```
/^\w+([\-+\.']\w+)*@\w+([\-\.]\w+)*\.\w+([\-\.]\w+)*$/
```

If you do not know regular expressions, I suggest that you learn them right away, since they are a pretty powerful and useful feature when dealing with and validating string content.

Comment: Still, the asker wants a non-regex method. Do you know their situation well enough that you can be sure they have regex available? Maybe they are using an old enough system to not support them?